# Vuejs array input in v-for

Tags: vue.js, v-for, v-model

i have a simple form about person's info. I have a persons count, for example 3. I need to send json like this:

```
{
  persons[0].surname: '',
  persons[0].name: '',
  persons[0].something'',
  persons[1].surname: '',
  persons[1].name: '',
  persons[1].something'',
  persons[2].surname: '',
  persons[2].name: '',
  persons[2].something'',
}
```

I have set up my form like this

```
 <template v-for="(person, person_index) in people">
<input type="text" placeholder="surname">
<input type="text" placeholder="name">
<input type="text" placeholder="something">
</template>
```

and my data:

```
data() {
    return {
        persons: [],
        people: 3
},

methods: { 
    save(){
        console.log(this.persons);
    } 
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: @MaxSinev how should i bind v-model, to get in save method format like this: {
  persons[0].surname: '',
  persons[0].name: '',
  persons[0].something'',
  persons[1].surname: '',
  persons[1].name: '',
  persons[1].something'',
  persons[2].surname: '',
  persons[2].name: '',
  persons[2].something'',
}

Comment: Who will be providing the values of `persons`? The user via the `input` element or do you already have this info available?

Comment: @kingJulian user via the input

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood what you are asking, is a way to update the `persons` object with the value of the input element.

In `Vue` this is done using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` [method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). In code:

```
methods: { 
    save: function (){
        this.$set(this.persons, index, value); //for Vue 2.x
        console.log(this.persons);
    } 
}
```

or

```
methods: { 
    save: function (){
        Vue.set(this.persons, index, value) //for Vue 1.x
        console.log(this.persons);
    } 
}
```

where index and value correspond to your `input` elements. Just make sure to also add these attributes in your input elements.

Comment: and i don't need to bind v-model for my inputs?

Comment: If I've correctly understood what you're asking then no. You can look at the link I provided for more details. Also, I just noticed that your `<template>` code needs to be corrected. Your `person` object is empty so you cannot iterate over it to create the 3 inputs.

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider also accepting it as a correct answer so future users of SO can benefit from it too.